# How can I add a question to forawait readline in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, asynchronous, generator

I was browsing the nodejs docs for some functionality, and I spot a `forawait` functionality but I couldn't apply a question to it.

here is the docs example:

```js
async function processLineByLine() {
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    // ...
  });

  for await (const line of rl) {
    // Each line in the readline input will be successively available here as
    // `line`.
  }
}
```

here is my attempt:

```js
const readline = require('readline');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false,
});

const promptUserCLI = (q, exitAnswers = [], callback) => {
  rl.question(q, answer => {
    if (exitAnswers.includes(answer)) {
      rl.close();
    } else {
      callback(null, answer);
    }
  });
};


const promptPromise = promisify(promptUserCLI)

// this data must have some relation to the question.
// --  and therefore I have to iterate over it somehow in a clean way.
const data = require('./file.json');

async function processLineByLine(callback) {
  rl[Symbol.asyncIterator] = async function* () {
    let index = 0
    while (true) {
      const item = data[index]

      const answer = await promptPromise(`Make '${item.line}' [ [y]es/no/all/exit ]`, ['exit', 'quite'])

      index += 1

      return {
        async * next() {
          yield { answer, item, index }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  for await (const line of rl) {
    let isClosed = false
    const close = () => isClosed = true
    callback(line, close)

    if (isClosed) break
  }
}

// uncomment for testing: this should log(line, [Function: close])
// -- Note: line should have: { answer, item, index }
// processLineByLine(console.log)


// my best shot was using raw generator, yet, this doesn't break out the loop if I intended to use `break` keyword
async function* gen() {
  let index = 0
  while (true) {
    const item = data[index]

    const answer = await promptPromise(`Make '${item.line}' [ [y]es/no/all/exit ]`, ['exit', 'quite'])

    index += 1

    yield { answer, item, index }
  }
}

// this is a perfect example of it "almost" working as I need
;; (async () => {
  try {
    for await (const item of gen()) {
      console.log('item', item)

      // the break here won't break, if this get solved I'm good, that's all I need.
      break
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
})()
```

a little snapshot of how the data could look like.

```json
[
  {
    "line": "Lorem ipsum verties sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
    "replacements": [],
    "indices": [
      0
    ]
  },
  {
    "line": "Vivamus tincidunt verties sit amet libero laoreet aliquet.",
    "replacements": [],
    "indices": [
      0
    ]
  },
  {
    "line": "Nulla sodales ipsum verties lorem elementum, vitae porttitor nisi pellentesque.",
    "replacements": [],
    "indices": [
      0
    ]
  },
  {
    "line": "Nullam verties dui eget nulla facilisis porttitor.",
    "replacements": [],
    "indices": [
      0
    ]
  }
]
```

Ps: I didn't know How can I add a question to my `for await` readline generator•

do you have an idea?

replit: https://replit.com/@meno101/temp#index.js
source: https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#rlsymbolasynciterator

Comment: If you want to use [`rl.question`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#rlquestionquery-options) instead of reading all the input line by line, don't use the async iterator?!

Comment: you maybe right, but my intention is to make it cleaner, and I felt this way is the cleanest, don't you agree?

Comment: I don't think that using callbacks with an `async`/`await` interface is clean, and on top of that the code doesn't work so it seems futile to argue? Maybe I can suggest something if you post your whole code, including how `processLineByLine` is called, and also a working (but ugly) version of the code so I can see how it is supposed to work.

Comment: Thank you for sticking with me, I have made replit, I hope it could do the job: https://replit.com/@meno101/temp#index.js

Comment: I have made few adjustment since our last message

Comment: I don't see any edits to the question? Please add your code there

Comment: I have updated the question, thank you for the mention, it's good idea 

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your collaboration, if you find any answer for this question please feel free to post it, otherwise I figured wasting too much time on a simple task isn't worth my while.

curious? I removed the forawait part, and added an `rl.close()` after the loop after calling `gen` generator in the IIFE part, if I break out I will have it do the job for me.

```js
;; (async () => {
  try {
    for await (const item of gen()) {
      console.log('item', item)

      // the break here won't break, if this get solved I'm good, that's all I need.
      break
    }
    rl.close()
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
})()
```